# Continuous camera capture in Win8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime

I need to be able to continuously capture and process images in a Win8/Win8.1 application. Is there a way to do so without using the CaptureUI? Basically once my app is launched it has to continuously capture and process an image. I'm wondering if there is any already available API I could use to interact with the webcam and get the data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the media capture api, here's an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452791.aspx

Now the example pipes this to a file, but I think you'll get the idea by looking at the API how you can use it.